# computing and formatting averages and squares of time intervals

Tags: r, time

I have a model which predicts the duration of certain events, and measures of durations for those events. I then want to compute the difference between Predicted and Measured, the mean difference and the RMSE. I'm able to do it, but the formatting is really awkward and not what I expected:

```
database <- data.frame(Predicted = c(strptime(c("4:00", "3:35", "3:38"), format = "%H:%M")),
                       Measured = c(strptime(c("3:39", "3:40", "3:53"), format = "%H:%M")))
database
>             Predicted            Measured
1 2016-11-28 04:00:00 2016-11-28 03:39:00
2 2016-11-28 03:35:00 2016-11-28 03:40:00
3 2016-11-28 03:38:00 2016-11-28 03:53:00
```

This is the first weirdness: why does R shows me a time **and** a date, even if I clearly specified a time-only format (`%H:%M`), and there was no date in my data to start with? It gets weirder:

```
database$Error <- with(database, Predicted-Measured)
database$Mean_Error <- with(database, mean(Predicted-Measured))
database$RMSE <- with(database, sqrt(mean(as.numeric(Predicted-Measured)^2)))
> database
            Predicted            Measured    Error Mean_Error     RMSE
1 2016-11-28 04:00:00 2016-11-28 03:39:00  21 mins  0.3333333 15.17674
2 2016-11-28 03:35:00 2016-11-28 03:40:00  -5 mins  0.3333333 15.17674
3 2016-11-28 03:38:00 2016-11-28 03:53:00 -15 mins  0.3333333 15.17674
```

Why is the variable `Error` expressed in minutes? For `Error` it's not a bad choice, but it becomes quite hard to read for `Mean_Error`. For `RMSE` it's even worse, but this could be due to the `as.numeric` function: if I remove it, R complains that `'^' not defined for "difftime" objects`. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to show the first 2 columns (`Predicted` and `Measured`) shown in the `%H:%M` format?
2. for the other 3 columns ( `Error`, `Mean_Error` and `RMSE`) I would like to compare a `%M:%S` format and a format in only seconds, and choose among the two. Is it possible?

**EDIT**: just to be more clear, my goal is to insert observations of time intervals into a dataframe and compute a vector of time interval differences. Then, compute some statistics for that vector: mean, RMSE, etc.. I know I could just enter the time observations in seconds, but that doesn't look very good: it's difficult to tell that 13200 seconds are 3 hours and 40 minutes. Thus I would like to be able to store the time intervals in the `%H:%M`, but then be able to manipulate them algebraically and show the results in a format of my choosing. Is that possible?

Comment: For the first weirdness, `strptime` converts to `POSIXlt` and it will add today's date to it. To display only the hour and minute use: `format(strptime(c("4:00", "3:35", "3:38"), format = "%H:%M"), format="%H:%M")` which are just characters (i.e., you lose the date-time class)

Comment: @aichao, I tried `database$Predicted <- format(strptime(database$Predicted, format = "%H:%M"), format="%H:%M")`, but I got `> database$Predicted
[1] NA NA NA`. I guess the real issue here is that I don't need a Date-Time object, but more something like a time interval object...is it possible to obtain that?
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `difftime` to specify the units for the difference in time. The output of `difftime` is an object of class `difftime`. When this `difftime` object is coerced to numeric using `as.numeric`, we can change these units (see the examples in `?difftime`):

```
## Note we don't convert to date-time because we just want %H:%M
database <- data.frame(Predicted = c("4:00", "3:35", "3:38"),
                       Measured = c("3:39", "3:40", "3:53"))
## We now convert to date-time and use difftime to compute difference in minutes
database$Error <- with(database, difftime(strptime(Predicted,format="%H:%M"),strptime(Measured,format="%H:%M"), units="mins"))
## Use as.numeric to change units to seconds
database$Mean_Error <- with(database, mean(as.numeric(Error,units="secs")))
database$RMSE <- with(database, sqrt(mean(as.numeric(Error,units="secs")^2)))
##  Predicted Measured    Error Mean_Error     RMSE
##1      4:00     3:39  21 mins         20 910.6042
##2      3:35     3:40  -5 mins         20 910.6042
##3      3:38     3:53 -15 mins         20 910.6042
```